# How to enter real full screen mode in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

With the code below I tried to enter real full screen mode in macOS. If `nil` is passed as options then it enters kind of full screen mode, but no content is visible.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let opts: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [.fullScreen]

        var options = [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey: Any]()
        options[.fullScreenModeAllScreens] = 0
        // options[.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions] = opts.rawValue
        view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.main!, withOptions: options)
    }
}
```

How to make the content visible or is there another way to enter full screen mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell the ViewController's window to expand into fullscreen mode:

```
self.view.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
```

Comment: It seems this only works as long as my code is moved to `viewDidAppear()`. With a SceneKit view (SCNView) the main menu is still visible. Could not find a working option to also hide the main menu.

Comment: When I exit to full-screen app is stuck any solution?